# Proper encoding of href for window.open() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

What is the proper cross-browser encoding for the href when using `window.open()` in JavaScript? First I was using

```
var href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/etf/admin/escola/t34atividade/?pop=1&copy=1";
var win = window.open(href, name, 'height=500,width=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
```

IE8 opens: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/etf/admin/escola/t34atividade/?pop=1©=1`

FireFox opens: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/etf/admin/escola/t34atividade/?pop=1&copy=1`

```
var href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/etf/admin/escola/t34atividade/?pop=1&amp;copy=1";
var win = window.open(href, name, 'height=500,width=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
```

IE8 opens: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/etf/admin/escola/t34atividade/?pop=1&copy=1`

FireFox opens: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/etf/admin/escola/t34atividade/?pop=1&amp;copy=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I found was to stop using `copy` as a GET parameter. The problem is that `&copy` is actually an HTML entity for the copyright symbol. IE applies an entity replacement converting it to the symbol even though it's in JavaScript code. Apparently Firefox does not perform the entity replacement. According to a comment in this blog what IE is doing might be correct, but to avoid all the mess I just renamed my parameter to `clone`.

http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200812/accidental_html_entities_in_urls.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the Javascript "encodeURIComponent" function for each piece of the URI that's *not* part of the URI syntax (that is, separator slashes, the question mark for the query string, parameter separator ampersands, etc).

URI encoding is **not** the same as HTML escaping.  For example, you don't escape an ampersand in a URL as `&amp;`.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. I added some background info below. Would have added it in a comment here but I couldn't get the right behavior from entities.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you provide an example? When I pass the string "copy" to encodeURIComponent() it doesn't do anything and when I pass the string "&" it encodes it as %26 in the new URL which isn't what I want either. I want to have two parameters in my GET copy and pop which are both set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 appears to be trying to coerce the query string argument **&copy=1** to the entity **&copy;**, which is the copyright symbol (©). That is actually funny. Just like Microsoft to encumber the user with "help".

Pointy is correct about encoding. Be careful also that you don't have a code minifier that removes everything on a line after a pair of double slashes (//); I've seen those wreck pages before.